# What Is This Chord? Is It A Ab5?

Tags: analysis

This is Tchaikovsky's The Doll's Funeral, which is in C minor. The chord I am confused about is the second chord in measure 30. I should mention this is my first time analyzing. I thought this was some sort of borrowed chord, but the only chords that responded to the notes Ab D F# were a Db5 and a Ab7b5sus. Am I missing some sort of knowledge here? [image]

Answer (score 4):

The second chord of Bar 30 is best explained as a **passing chord**, as it is sandwiched between two differently voiced German Augmented 6th chords and uses D instead of their C and E flat.

Alternately, you could explain it as an incompletely voiced French Augmented 6th chord. In C minor, a French Augmented 6th chord uses the notes A flat, C, D, and F sharp.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an Italian Sixth. In the keys of C major and minor, it's built on the minor sixth above the tonic (not why it's called the Augmented Sixth) with a minor third and an augmented sixth interval above the bass (that's why it's called the Augmented Sixth; it can also appear on other notes, often on a flat second step). The augmented sixth resolves outward by half-step to the octave on scale step 5 (if based on step 6); sometimes through a I64 and sometimes directly to a V chord.

Notice that it's written with an F# to distinguish it from an Ab7 chord. The chord appears with the fifth above its bass (German Sixth) and sometimes with a diminished fifth above its bass (French Sixth). Though enharmonic to some seventh chords, it resolves differently. It's normally used as a pre-dominant.

Comment: Isn't it German?  I see Ab, C, Eb, and F# clearly on beat 1 of 30

Comment: The question asks for the **second** chord of Bar 30, not the first like your answer indicates.